# Sorting array from max to min taking from array post custom field date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi all I am new in php and I need yor help.

I do something in wordpress I create posts and with advanced custom field i write date in every post so I need to sort array of posts from max to min taking custom fields dates how can I do that?

my code

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'        => 'events',
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        );

    $posts_array = get_posts($args); posts array;

/// need some sort function
/// for taking post field date get_field("date", $posts_array[0]->ID);

 ////echo date from posts array
    foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        $category_Post_Id=$post->ID;
        $date = get_field("date", $category_Post_Id);

        echo $date . ", ";
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

thanks for your help

dump

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Post)#123 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(17)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:36:04"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:36:04"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(23) "asfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(8) "events-4"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(8) "events-4"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:36:31"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:36:31"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(50) "http://localhost/lorig/?post_type=events&p=17"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(6) "events"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Post)#293 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(15)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:34:03"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:34:03"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(10) "eatsdfasdf"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(8) "events-3"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(8) "events-3"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:34:03"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:34:03"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(50) "http://localhost/lorig/?post_type=events&p=15"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(6) "events"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(WP_Post)#294 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(13)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:37"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:37"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(13) "afsdfasdfasdf"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(8) "events-2"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(8) "events-2"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:37"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:37"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(50) "http://localhost/lorig/?post_type=events&p=13"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(6) "events"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(WP_Post)#295 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(11)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:10"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:10"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(15) "sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(8) "events 1"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(8) "events-1"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:10"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2015-07-09 08:33:10"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(50) "http://localhost/lorig/?post_type=events&p=11"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(6) "events"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your array structure along with expected output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)